# How to get Window from an InputMethodService?

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager

Is it possible to get the Window object for a particular View (or `PopupWindow`)?

**My app is a keyboard so it is a Service (an `InputMethodService`), not an Activity.** Therefore I cannot use `Activity.getWindow()`. However, it has Views, so it presumably has a Window too, no? How do I get it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Very good question, indeed.  I can think of two possible approaches: (1) use `View.getWindowToken` and then try to get to the window from the retrieved `IBinder` interface.  I have no idea what the implementation of it is, so you can try to use reflection to see what you got back; (2) use `Context.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)` to get the WindowManager - and try going from there.  I haven't tried either of the two, hence posting this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @AleksG: Sorry for this late reply. I already tried both your suggestions but nothing worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    InputMethodService ims;
    ...
    Dialog dialog = ims.getWindow();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
```

or simply:

```
    Window window = ims.getWindow().getWindow();
```

(This works with an InputMethodService and is not necessarily applicable to other Services.)

Comment: How could I initialize InputMethodService object 'ims' ?